# Spring authenticating ldap example and real ldap server

Tags: java, spring, ldap

long time listener, first time caller.

I have downloaded the spring authenticating ldap example at: 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/
into STS. It works fine.

However, I'd like to try and get it working with a real ldap database such as the one the kind folks at forumsys.com have made available:
http://www.forumsys.com/en/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/

My current configuration for configureGlobal is:

```
    @Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) throws Exception {

    authBuilder
        .ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchFilter("(uid={0},dc=example,dc=com)")
        .userSearchBase("")
        .contextSource()
            .url("ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389/dc=example,dc=com")
       .managerDn("cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com") 
            .managerPassword("password");

}
```

This returns a bad credentials error when I try to login with "tesla/password" or "einstein/password".
Would anyone be able to advise what setup in configureGlobal would result in a valid login?

Thanks,
Sore

Comment: Answering my own question.
In case anyone wishes to get the above working try:

    authBuilder  
                .ldapAuthentication()  
                .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")  
                .userSearchBase("")  
                .contextSource()  
                    .url("ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389/dc=example,dc=com")  
               .managerDn("cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com")   
                    .managerPassword("password");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
authBuilder
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
            .userSearchBase("")
            .contextSource()
                .url("ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389/dc=example,dc=com")
           .managerDn("cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com") 
                .managerPassword("password");
```